# How to get a named branch?

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am using LibGit2Sharp and would like to get the latest commit of a specific branch, but, due to lacking documentation or my own fault I cannot find out how to achieve this.

Therefore, what's the easiest way to get the current commit of a specific branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample to get the latest commit in a branch.

```
        IRepository repository = new Repository(@"D:\Code\MYRepoLocation\.git");

        foreach (var branch  in repository.Branches)
        {
            var listOfCommits = branch.Commits;
            var latestCommit = listOfCommits.First();
        }
```

You could also pick a specific branch by giving its name

```
var myBranch2Dot0 = repository.Branches["bug2.0"];
```

**Note:** These are the branches available locally, and not the one in `Remote`

Comment: @jacobaloysious: In order to retrieve the latest commit of a branch, the easiest way is `var commit = repo.Branches[branch_name].Tip;` ;-)